# 'HwndElementInfo' object has no attribute 'automation_id'

Tags: pywinauto

I am trying to find a child window using pywinauto, no success and getting the error stated in the question title.

**code**

```
wnd_spec.child_window(control_type='UIA_PaneControlTypeId (0xC371)', auto_id='PanelFields')
```

**Inspect.exe**

```
Name: ""
ControlType: UIA_PaneControlTypeId (0xC371)
LocalizedControlType: "pane"
AutomationId: "PanelFields"
FrameworkId: "WinForm"
```

I am running/connecting to the application with backend=win32 to avoid the NoPatternInterface Error.

Any help will be much appreciated

Comment: The error says `automation_id`, your code says `auto_id`, and Inspect says `AutomationId`. Are those all correct?

Comment: underscore_d, if you go through the source code, the doc string states to pass the keyword as auto_id. https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto/blob/master/pywinauto/findwindows.py

Comment: win32 backend doesn’t provide auto_id property in current release. But this is implemented in master branch (not released yet) so you can try master branch.

Comment: Thank you so much Vasily, a solution at sight. I will try with the master branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is implemented in `pywinauto==0.6.5`. Now you can use `auto_id` and `control_type` search properties for "win32" backend as well. It should work fine especially for WinForms apps.

P.S. Of course, `control_type` property value looks simpler than Inspect.exe shows. Please rely on `print_control_identifiers()` output for this.